# Subalgebras of the tensor product $A'\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}F$

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $F$ of positive characteristic with prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Regarding $A$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Assume that there is a subalgebra $A'$ of $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $A=A'\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}F$. Let $x$ be an element of $A$ and let $A_x$ be the $\mathbb{F}_p$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by $x$.

I am trying to check that there is a subalgebra $A'_x$ of $A_x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $A_x=A'_x\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}F$.

Any counterexample reference or technique is very much appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: This can't possibly be true. Do you maybe want $A_x$ to be a $F$-subalgebra? But even then, take $x = 1 \otimes u$...